# CoreText is not loading custom fonts

Tags: ios, core-text, core-foundation

I have two custom .ttf and .otf fonts. I am  trying to load them in CoreText using this line of code:

```
CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Ronnia"), self.fontSize, NULL);
```

Frustratingly it works with installed fonts like 'American Typewriter'. But what is more confusing is that I found my installed custom fonts work with UILabels `fontWithName`

Answer (score 1):

In order to use custom fonts in iOS, just add your fonts by drag & drop to your project. Mention the array of font names with extension in Info.plist with key "Fonts provided by application". Then print all font family names using below code :

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
  DebugLog(@"FONT FAMILY: %@", family);

  for (NSString *name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
  {
    DebugLog(@"  %@", name);
  }
}
```

Console print :

> **Arial Hebrew**
>   ArialHebrew-Bold
>   ArialHebrew-Light
>   ArialHebrew
>   
>   **Calibri**
>   Calibri-Bold
>   Calibri
>   
>   **Georgia**
>    Georgia-BoldItalic
>    Georgia-Bold
>    Georgia-Italic
>    Georgia

Then from console, you will get the actual font-names (As above). Use below code to create font -

In core text :
`CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)fontName, fontSize, NULL);`

In UIKit :
`UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:10];`

Note : here `fontName = @"Calibri-Bold"` is without extension.

Answer (score -1):

If the custom fonts work with UILabel, then it should be able to work in CoreText as

```
fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)fontName, fontSize, NULL);
```

after you create the font, you need to set it as fontRef for value kCTFontAttributeName in the attributed-dictionary for the NSAttributedString. It works for me.